# Python Qlistview output dir

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistview

i wish make little gui with pyqt4 that show the output of "dir c:\windows\" line by line
I'm looking for QlistView but i don't understand how do it.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [QListWidget](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlistwidget.html) instead of [QListView](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlistview.html).  QListWidget extends QListView and adds some very helpful methods like `addItems`.

I'm going to assume you know how to create the GUI part of the application using Designer.

If you have a QListWidget object `qlistwidget`, the code would be:

```
values = os.listdir("c:\\windows")

qlist = QtCore.QStringList(map(QtCore.QString, values))
qlistwidget.addItems(qlist)
```

Comment: Thanks this work! I do it also with QlistView (i made an array and then print the value on Qlistview). If i want to do some action like select one file and copy it in the same dir with another extension can you suggest how do it? Thanks for your replay

Comment: Check out `shutil.copy(src, dst)`, http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\windows'):
    //add your QlistView add codes here
```

Comment: Hi Mark
thanks for your fast replay.
For list dir i use: 

for filename in os.listdir("c:\\windows"):
    print  filename

My problem is port the output of command inside the gui (I'm looking for QlistView but i don't know how do it)

Comment: @ester23, if gui is under your control, you can directly use os.listdir results, instead of printing to console and getting results back.

Comment: Yes is under my control. Is only a test for learn pyqt. I wish print line by line because i want do some action on file (like rename, make a copy, etc). But i'm not know the way for do it so i read about QlistView but i don't know how let work this. Thanks for your help